# Firebase not recognizing associated domains when using ActionCodesSettings with Auth.sendEmailVerification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

On iOS/Swift, I am receiving an unexpected domain error when using [sendEmailVerification(with:completion:)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#/c:objc(cs)FIRUser(im)sendEmailVerificationWithActionCodeSettings:completion:). I have used Dynamic Links manually to set up the associated domain.

```
let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = false
email = "user@domain.com"
actionCodeSettings.url = "https://example.page.link/verify?email=\(email)"

user.sendEmailVerification( with: actionCodeSettings )
{
    ( error ) in
    ...
}
```

The error is:

> Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17038 "Domain not whitelisted by project" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Domain not whitelisted by project, error_name=ERROR_UNAUTHORIZED_DOMAIN}), Optional(https://example.page.link/verify?email=user@domain.com)

However, when I look at the binary using `codesign -d --entitlements`, the domain is listed.

```
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>MYTEAMID.com.devdomain.example</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:example.page.link</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>MYTEAMID</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Further, [example.page.link/apple-app-site-association](https://example.page.link/apple-app-site-association) shows the correct information.

Do I need to otherwise tell Firebase that the domain is whitelisted? How?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues in your implementation.

1. `actionCodeSettings.url` should be the deep link and not the FDL link `example.page.link`.
2. The deep link domain you pass must be whitelisted in the list of authorized domains in the Firebase Console (this is the main reason behind the unauthorized domain error).
3. Right now, Firebase Auth doesn't allow customizing of the dynamic link `example.page.link`. It will always pick the first dynamic link available.

Comment: For #2, this needed to be authorized in the Authentication/Sign-in Method. I only had it whitelisted in Dynamic Links.  Thank you!